# Page by page conversion rate in Google Anlytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to get the conversion rate for a specific page in Google Analytics. I am looking for results like you get from using Behavior > Site Content > Landing Pages. The issue is that this source only shows results if you landed on that page. I have pages that are reached using the navigation and since they are not landing pages I cannot track their conversion.

Does anyone have a technique to get a specific pages conversion rate?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create a custom report that has page as dimension and conversion rates(goal and e-commerce) as metrics
this is how it would look like
http://take.ms/NFjbL

Comment: Nice found, that convertions are the pageview/convertions or the converting sessions that goes through these page?

Comment: I set this custom report up: https://i.imgsafe.org/306010e8a8.png but when I view results the only pages it can find is the /thanks pages. This is my issue, every custom report I tried only show /thanks as having a conversion of 100%, no other pages are included. Any ideas?

Comment: This is because you're only using your goal as metric.

these are the metrics that you should use.
http://take.ms/53hIB

Comment: I now have that same setup except my goal names are different. My results are still the same all pages on the site have 0 goal completion and 0 goal conversion rate. The /thanks page has all the conversions and 100% conversion rate. You can see some results here: https://i.imgsafe.org/450a8a79b4.png. Could it be the way my goal is setup? Here is the setup of my goal: https://i.imgsafe.org/4507749bf2.png

Comment: hey you have sorted pages in the reports, sort the goal conversions in order to get the results

Comment: Yes I have sorted them and the only page that has any conversions is "/thanks" which is actually the goal page. All other pages are 0.

Answer (score 0):

What you want by concept is very weird, the convertion rate is based on session level and the pageview is on a hit level (the complication comes on this level), this due one session can see many page views beign the session the convertion object, so what i can recomend you is use a Segment (no filter) to see the user that goes througth a page and finish converting .

This solution can be applies to all the pages, only to one, now if you what to do to all your pages you can use the pagevalue metric.